# Auth user with a Key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to make an auth page to my website with only a Key field.

[image]

Example : I give an Key like 'A5DP7123OAC' to my customer for the login.

And if the code is correct he can access to his panel. Actually I just create a Cookie :

```
withCookie(cookie()->forever('access', 'true'));
```

But it's not a good way I think.

Do you have solution to Auth an user only with a Key ?

Thank's

Comment: If that code is unique a solution would be to get the user from db based on that code and do a Auth::login($user);

Comment: If i use Auth::login($user); the request will be on the user table, I have a dedicated table pour my customer key. User is empty

Comment: Maybe make a related table for that customer key then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass your key to the session and then check to see if the key the user provides matches the key in the session. If so you can log the user in manually using one of the methods found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#other-authentication-methods

If you don't want to use the session, you could also create a DB table and store your keys there optionally giving them expirations so that the keys are only valid for a period of time. You could also make it so that keys are only valid for one IP address. Plenty of options.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. If I use the Auth:: class the request will be in the "User" table for the authentiation. And the Auth:: class required username and table

Comment: If you  store your keys in a DB table, you can create an eloquent object form them. Then you can implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` contract on your key model. Then update your `config/auth.php` file to take into account your new authentication method. Then you can use your key model with the auth methods